# JSONArray to ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I get jsonarray as following from server "dataArray":

```json
[{"FirstNmae":"xyz","BranchId":"asd","Location":"qwe"}]
```

Now I want to create `ArrayList<EmpData>` list using Gson where `EmpData` is normal Pojo class. Below is my code which is getting error

```java
TypeToken<List<EmpData>> token = new TypeToken<List<EmpData>>() {};
List<EmpData> empList = gson.fromJson(dataArray, token.getType());
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without any loop is it possible in android ?

Comment: *"which is getting error"* What error? Please **edit** the question and show the error you are getting. We don't even know if you're talking about a compilation error or a runtime error.

Comment: At a guess, the weird mix of `EmpList` and `EmpData` is causing compilation error. --- *FYI:* Local variable names should start with lowercase letter, i.e. `empList`, not `EmpList`. --- It is the `EmpList` in the first line that looks suspicious.

Comment: that EmpList is typing mistake it is empList... and corrected my mistake in my question.... do you have any solution for this question?

Comment: Why are you converting the response to a `JSONArray` if you can deserialize directly from the response using Gson?

Comment: Additionally, why do you think that Gson has an overload for the `fromJson` method to accept `JSONArray` instances? (Hint: you're half way away of the final solution despite it's far from being perfect.)

Comment: @shirishbobade No, I have no solution to this question, because I don't know what is wrong with the code in the question. You never said what error you are getting. You fixed some compilation errors, and say that you still have other / same error as before? I cannot reproduce any errors now.

Comment: @shirishbobade So, you're posting a question even not bothering fixing the compilation error. Well... It's not good, because it's the key. Also, if you want to have it "loopless", you have to know that the loop will be hidden anyway in either library code or the code of yours. As I said: if you fix your compilation error (I still assume `dataArray` is an instance `JSONArray`) by using one of the `fromJson` method overloads, you're done with this. It's extremely easy to find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Not an answer**, but included as an answer to show formatted code.*

**Unable to reproduce**. Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), based on the information in the question, and it runs fine.

The code uses public fields for simplicity. Real code would likely use private fields and getter/setter methods, but since the POJO is not the question, I kept this simple.

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Code from question starts here

String dataArray = "[{\"FirstNmae\":\"xyz\",\"BranchId\":\"asd\",\"Location\":\"qwe\"}]";

TypeToken<List<EmpData>> token = new TypeToken<List<EmpData>>() {};
List<EmpData> empList = gson.fromJson(dataArray, token.getType());

// Code from question ends here

System.out.println("dataArray = " + dataArray);
System.out.println("empList = " + empList);
```

```java
class EmpData {
    @SerializedName("FirstNmae")
    public String firstName;
    @SerializedName("BranchId")
    public String branchId;
    @SerializedName("Location")
    public String location;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmpData[firstName=" + this.firstName +
                     ", branchId=" + this.branchId +
                     ", location=" + this.location + "]";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
dataArray = [{"FirstNmae":"xyz","BranchId":"asd","Location":"qwe"}]
empList = [EmpData[firstName=xyz, branchId=asd, location=qwe]]
```

Notice how the `@SerializedName` annotation is used to handle the typo in the name (`FirstNmae`), as well as the uppercase/lowercase issue of the first letter in the names.

Comment: I do believe OP's `dataArray` is an instance of `JSONArray`, and this is what they referred as error, despite no compile-time/runtime error was provided though.

Comment: @fluffy The code works exactly the same if `dataArray` is a `JsonArray`, e.g. as a result of `JsonArray dataArray = gson.fromJson(json, JsonArray.class);`, where `json` is the `dataArray` string shown in this answer.

Comment: No, Gson and its `Gson.fromJson` method overloads family cannot work with `org.json.JSONArray` (as it appears right in the question). Anyway, the question is unclear and the OP makes no turn to clarify it.

Comment: @fluffy Why do you believe OP is mixing in a class from a different JSON library? It works fine if `dataArray` is a `com.google.gson.JsonArray`. Given the lack of casing in the question, "jsonarray" can be either class or just a reference to a `[ ]` JSON Array text string, as shown in this answer. I think you're making more assumptions here than I am.

Comment: The OP refers the source array class as `JSONArray`, an Android built-in from the `org.json` package. If the OP would refer as `JsonArray`, they would have no issues with that (besides that I've seen a couple of questions here where their OPs mixed `JSONArray`/`JsonArray` and `JSONObject`/`JsonObject`). This makes me think the OP has to convert the `JSONArray` instance at least to a string so that `fromJson` woud work. (While I was writing this comment, the OP accepted this answer, so they definitely had no errors they were claiming about or... let's call it "whatever else".)

Comment: @fluffy You're right, I was reading the question, where OP says `jsonarray`. I didn't notice the alternate casing of `JSONArray` in the title. Of course, if OP had simply posted the error like we asked, this could have been settled much faster.